# OSRM-BACKEND docker: Local server accepts no more than 500 point

Tags: docker, server, osrm

I send points using leaflet-routing-machine, but after 500 entry passed I get this error:

```
{ message: Number of entries 527 is higher than current maximum (500), code: Too Big }
```

How can I increase size number of entries in docker osrm-backend?